# Reorganization of namespaces

Tags: plugins, oop, namespace, autoloading

First of all thank You for Your time.
I use autoload in my 2 plugins. They have to different namespaces but i want to build one main plugin with autoload for this two plugins. In future i am going to add more plugins. How should i organize that? 
in plugins i have to namespaces

`namespace plugin_namespace\controller\some_cntr` and

`namespace sec_plugin_namespace\controller\some_cntr`

everything is object oriented and here is my autoloader witch exists in both plugins (i will have only one if it is possible :))

```
 /**
 * Register autoloader
 */
public function autoloader(){
    spl_autoload_register( array( $this, 'xx_my_plugin' ) );
}

/**
 * Autoloader
 *
 * @param $class
 */
public function xx_my_plugin( $class ) {
    $first = strpos($class, '\\') + 1;
    $path = substr( $class, $first);
    $path = strtolower( $path );
    $path = str_replace( '_', '-', $path );
    $path = str_replace( '\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path ) . '.php';
    $path = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $path;

    if ( file_exists( $path ) ) {
        include $path;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Problem solved. I added plugin as i said to manage autoloader and other stuff. I changed my autoloader and thanks to that i have one in place of 3. Solution was to change one piece of directory with plugin name.This is my autoloader now:

```
public function xx_main_plugin( $class ) {

    $array = explode('\\', $class);
    $plugin = str_replace('_', '-', $array[0]);
    $dir =  str_replace( 'in-this-plugin-is-autoloader', $plugin, __DIR__);

    $first = strpos($class, '\\') + 1;
    $path = substr( $class, $first);
    $path = strtolower( $path );
    $path = str_replace( '_', '-', $path );
    $path = str_replace( '\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path ) . '.php';
    $path = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $path;

    if ( file_exists( $path ) ) {
        include $path;
    }
}
```